# Load angular2 dependencies with Systemjs

Tags: angular, systemjs

I have been studying angular2 for a while following the official site. Since SystemJS seems to be the recommended module loader, I'm trying to use it.
From the official quick start (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) the following index.html example loading an angular2 project can be found:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to load everything with systemJS, reaching this situation:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 2. Loading SystemJS -->
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you would use ***angular-cli*** (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to help you generate a new project and do all the configs and hard work for you. It will help you a lot and you will save time believe me. Things are changing a lot right now so it will be easier for you to have a good friend like angular-cli in your journey.

If you don't want to use it, the you can create a file like ***system-config.js*** that will contain something like this, you can add in ***barrels*** object specific libraries that you want:

```
var map = {};
/** User packages configuration. */
var packages = {};

var barrels = [
    // Angular specific barrels.
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    // Thirdparty barrels.
    'rxjs',
    // App specific barrels.
    'app',
    'app/shared',
];
var cliSystemConfigPackages = {};
barrels.forEach(function (barrelName) {
    cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'index' };
});
// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
    map: {
        '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
        'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
        'main': 'main.js'
    },
    packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});
// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map: map, packages: packages });
```

and then in your index.html file you can have:

```
<script>
  System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
    System.import('app');
  }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wanted to try anglular-cli but I have read it's still in development and not that mature.

Comment: @GiovanniDiSanto you can use it. I'm using it also.